# Generating enumerator.Current instead of (int)((List<T>.Enumerator*)(byte*)enumerator)->Current

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I am currently working on an API.

Whenever the user marks a type with a certain attribute, I want to create a new `List<int>` field and loop through it, performing some operations.

Here is some relevant code:

```
TypeReference intTypeReference = moduleDefinition.ImportReference(typeof(int));

TypeReference listType = moduleDefinition.ImportReference(typeof(List<>));
GenericInstanceType intListType = listType.MakeGenericInstanceType(intTypeReference);

var numberList = 
    new FieldDefinition(
        name: "Numbers", 
        attributes: field.Attributes,
        fieldType: moduleDefinition.ImportReference(intListType));
generatedType.Fields.Add(numberList);

Type enumeratorType = typeof(List<>.Enumerator);

var enumeratorTypeReference = moduleDefinition.ImportReference(enumeratorType);
GenericInstanceType intEnumeratorType = enumeratorTypeReference.MakeGenericInstanceType(intTypeReference);

var enumeratorVariable = new VariableDefinition(intEnumeratorType);
convertMethod.Body.Variables.Add(enumeratorVariable);

ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, numberList); 

MethodReference getEnumeratorMethodReference =
    new MethodReference(
        name: "GetEnumerator",
        returnType: intEnumeratorType,
        declaringType: intListType)
    {
        HasThis = true
    };
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getEnumeratorMethodReference);
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, enumeratorVariable);

TypeDefinition enumeratorTypeDefinition = enumeratorTypeReference.Resolve();
MethodDefinition getCurrentMethod =
    enumeratorTypeDefinition.Properties.Single(p => p.Name == "Current").GetMethod;
MethodDefinition moveNextMethod = 
    enumeratorTypeDefinition.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "MoveNext");

MethodReference getCurrentMethodReference = moduleDefinition.ImportReference(getCurrentMethod);
MethodReference moveNextMethodReference = moduleDefinition.ImportReference(moveNextMethod);

// Call enumerator.Current
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, enumeratorVariable);
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getCurrentMethodReference);
// Store it inside currentVariable
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, currentVariable);
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
```

Here is the relevant output:

```
List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = Numbers.GetEnumerator();
int value = (int)((List<T>.Enumerator*)(byte*)enumerator)->Current;
```

`List<int>.Enumerator enumerator = Numbers.GetEnumerator();` is my desired result. However, `int value = (int)((List<T>.Enumerator*)(byte*)enumerator)->Current;` is obviously not what I want.

What should I do differently so that my output becomes `int value = enumerator.Current`, instead of the unreadable mess that it currently is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>.Enumerator` is a value type. As such, you need to be calling methods on the *address* of the `enumerator` variable, rather than on its value.

You also can't use `callvirt` on value types (although you can do constrained virtual calls, which is useful for calling some methods from `object`). You need to use `call` here. This isn't a problem, because value types can't be subclassed, so you know the exact method you're calling.

Therefore you need to:

```
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, enumeratorVariable);
ilProcessor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getCurrentMethodReference);
```

This explains why you're getting the strange decompiled output: the decompiler knows that `Current` can only be called on the address of `enumerator`, but it also sees that you're actually calling it on the value, so it concocts the cast to turn `enumerator` into a pointer to a `List<T>.Enumerator`.

You can see that [on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgCwG4CwAoGBmJAJgQGEEBvHBapAmVBAWQAoAZMAZ2AB4wA7YAD4EETsACUFKjRkA3AIYAnBAFM+AVwC2KxfOAB7ZQF4RYgHQBxFcACiG7boOLm4rNhkz+wBAGN1ixTVvEzUtHT1DMxJ/QIE3GQBfHASgA=).